# How can I transfer variables between pages in PHP?

Tags: php, html, forms, variables, authentication

I am trying to make a login form with PHP, and I want to get a value from a form like so:

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
```

then, when the user clicks "Submit", I want the new page to have access to these variables. Using the

```
include 'file1.php';
```

technically works, but I dont want ALL of 'file1.php', just the variables.
Any Suggestions?

Comment: You don't need to include anything. The page you're pointing your form to will have access to the `$_POST`

Comment: Use [`sessions`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) instead, along with what you have now - *"Easy as pie"* when dealing with included files; *believe me.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You have to use session. Here is a simple demonstration:

---

**page1.php** - Load page one to set the session variable

```
<?php
// begin the session
session_start(); 

// set the value of the session variable 'foo'
$_SESSION['foo']='bar'; 

// echo a little message to say it is done
echo 'Setting value of foo'; 
?>
```

**page2.php** - Load page two and it will have access to the session variable you set in `page1.php`

```
<?php 
// begin our session
session_start(); 

// echo the session variable
echo 'The value of foo is '.$_SESSION['foo']; 
?>
```

Comment: @user3330611 your welcome! If you don't mind could you mark this as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) are for.

> Sessions are a simple way to store data for individual users against a unique session ID. This can be used to persist state information between page requests. Session IDs are normally sent to the browser via session cookies and the ID is used to retrieve existing session data.